# What does the LED blinking on Arduino boot mean?

Tags: arduino

When an Arduino (Uno) starts, under some circumstances it flashes the pin 13 LED three times in quick succession, while in other circumstances it does not.

What does the LED blink indicate?

Under what conditions should it and should it not blink?

I think this is to do with the bootloader, but I'm not sure (and searching for "blink" in relation to the Arduino is not helpful). I find that if leave my bench power supply turned on and disconnect/reconnect power with a jumper, the rapid blink happens. The Arduino power LED also cuts out and comes on instantly.

If I turn off the power with the push button (soft button on digital PSU), the power LED on the arduino fades out quite slowly and back in rather faster, and the blink generally doesn't happen if the PSU is off for about 1sec, but the sketch does start afresh from setup(). If I turn off the bench supply, then remove the jumper, reconnect the jumper and turn back on, it blinks. That could be to do with disconnecting, or it could be to do with the time it takes to go through the process. If I turn the PSU off but leave connected, and turn back on after 2 seconds I get the blinks.

Comment: This is a user-level question having nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Sorry I have flagged this twice, by accident ([No mechanism for withdrawing an erroneously flagged post](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/no-mechanism-for-withdrawing-an-erroneously-flagged-post)

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion your first suspicion was right. It is the bootloader flashing the LED.

[This](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader?from=Main.Bootloader) page (scroll down to the section 'Versions of the bootloader') says:

> [...] The NG bootloader waits about 6-8 seconds and flashes the LED three times. [...]

The bootloader is signaling, that it is waiting for a new program to arrive.

Comment: Thanks. I've just worked out that the Arduino source download includes the bootloader source, and that confirms that the bootloader flashes. The number of times it flashes is set in the makefile and is different for different chips.

Answer (score 1):

In the bootloader version [here](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/trunk/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168.c), it flashes to indicate which UART (serial port) is used.